# I want to just use a simple for loop

Tags: arrays, swift

```
for i in 0..<self.etype.count{
    let item = self.etype[i]
    if (self.etype.contains("VALUE ACTIVITY")){
        print(self.etype.index(of: "VALUE ACTIVITY"))
    }

etype = [string]()
```

My etype has contain 5 values as follows:

> ["VALUE ACTIVITY", "BONUS ACTIVITY", ""JACKPOT EVENTS", "VALUE ACTIVITY", "JACKPOT EVENTS"]

I want to just replace the array that contains "VALUE ACTIVITY" with "Value", and "JACKPOT EVENTS" with "Jackpot", and "BONUS ACTIVITY" with "Bonus" that's it.

`print(self.etype.index(of: "VALUE ACTIVITY"))` always gives me `1`

Comment: That is because you are trying to print the index of the string in the array.

Comment: whats up with `for item in etype {}`

Comment: it should always give you 0, not 1

Comment: you dont need a for to use the if contains statement, or to check the index of a value. you dont actually use item or self.etype[i] anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to achieve the following:

```
import Foundation

let input = ["VALUE ACTIVITY", "BONUS ACTIVITY", "JACKPOT EVENTS", "VALUE ACTIVITY", "JACKPOT EVENTS"]

var output = [String]()

for element in input {
    if element.contains("VALUE ACTIVITY") {
        output.append(element.replacingOccurrences(of: "VALUE ACTIVITY", with: "Value"))
    } else if element.contains("JACKPOT EVENTS") {
        output.append(element.replacingOccurrences(of: "JACKPOT EVENTS", with: "Jackpot"))
    } else if element.contains("BONUS ACTIVITY") {
        output.append(element.replacingOccurrences(of: "BONUS ACTIVITY", with: "Bonus"))
    } else {
        output.append(element)
    }

}

print(output)
```

But in your specific case you could use a much shorter and more efficient solution:

```
import Foundation

let input = ["VALUE ACTIVITY", "BONUS ACTIVITY", "JACKPOT EVENTS", "VALUE ACTIVITY", "JACKPOT EVENTS"]

let output = input.map { $0.prefix(1).uppercased() + $0.split(separator: " ")[0].lowercased().dropFirst() }

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

How it works in simple form:

```
for index in 1...5 {

    print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")

}
```

Your example:

```
for i in 0..<self.etype.count {

    let item = self.etype[i]

    if (self.etype.contains("VALUE ACTIVITY")){

    print(self.etype.index(of: "VALUE ACTIVITY"))

}

etype = [string]()
```